# Simple login Java program

Tags: java, authentication

I'm very new to Java, and I want to make a very simple login Java-program.
Don't think about security issues and such in this example, I just need help to get it right.
My "Account informations" has to be stored in an Array.

This is my code:
-- MAIN --

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BATM {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String username;
    String password;

    System.out.println("Log in:");
    System.out.println("Indtast username: ");
    username = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Indtast password: ");
    password = input.nextLine();

    users check = new users(username, password);

    if(check.auth()) 
        System.out.println("You are logged in");



}

}
```

-- users ---

```
public class users {
private String username;
private String password;
private String[][] accounts = {{"jesper", "abc123"},{"christian", "abc123"}};

public users(String user, String pass){
    username = user;
    password = pass;
}

public boolean auth(){
    if((username == accounts[0][0]) && (password == accounts[0][1]))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

}
```

I guess this should be a quite simple function, but for some reason the if-statment will never return "true".

What am I doing wrong?

Jesper.

Comment: Which `if` statement?

Comment: if-statement in main, at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
if((username.equals(accounts[0][0])) && (password.equals(accounts[0][1])))
```

Comment: Hey, that did the trick.
Never stumbled upon the .equals() function before, but guess I need to use that from now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you are doing the string comparison wrong, in java you need to use `.equals()` isntead of `==`
the latter compares two object references, this is not what you want.

Comment: If I pass in the informations directly, "jesper" and "abc123", the if-statement is true. But for some reasons not when using the variable?

Comment: yes, this probably  because JVM is smart enough to use the same string object for the same string literal. all in all your use of `==` is wrong.

Comment: Hey Uku, your advice did the trick, thank you!

Comment: for future reference: objects in java implement a `equals` method. For java `String` this method is defined to compare the string values character by character. The correct way of comparing objects is using the `equals` method. Java also has primitive types like `ints` and `double`s, these are not `Object`s so you can compare them with `==`. Shortly put: never use "==" for comparing objects (this compares the object references, which are basically memory addresses).

Comment: Hi again, Uku. This it great info - I think the explains why the == operator works, in my world, "sometimes and sometimes not". :)